# Handle chat system with socket.io, nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I have to create a chat system for our client online shop, we use nodejs/mongodb/socket.io.

I just tested if the realtime conversation between my nodejs and a simple html page is working :

```
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("working");

});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);

});

    socket.emit('I just emit here for test', 'hello');
});
```

This code just working, now the fun part is to be able to make a shop manager discuss to a client, but clients shouldn't able to discuss between them (I have already a "clients" and "shop manager" collection ) like 
below picture :

[image: chat system with socket.io]

So, could someone tells me what is the best workflow to achieve this?, it means how to identify a client? and begin conversation to him? i am a bit lost with socket.io ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a message schema which will store conversations between client and manager.
2. Create a schema which will hold rooms or communication IDs.

Whenever a client logs into your system, show him the list of rooms, and when a client picks any room, show him the conversation.

Now, how to create a room?
Whenever a client wants to communicate with a manager (let's use ClientA and ManagerA), check if the conversation already exists or not. If a communication already exists, create a unique room like `"clientA-room-managerA"` and add both the parties to that room, store all the conversations in existing messages schema.

If the communication does not exist, create a room like `"clientA-room-managerA"` and then create a chat record in the schema which will hold communication Ids, and then start the room same as before `"clientA-room-managerA"`

By this way you should be able to create multiple chat records for a client and manager.

A client will not be able to communicate with other clients

A Manager can have communication with various clients

Consider a manager with user id: 123456789 and client with 0987654321, then you can create a room like:

```
var room = manager.user_id + "-room-" + client.user_id;
// room = 123456789-room-0987654321
//then join the client and manager to the room
manager_socket.join(room);
client_socket.join(room);

//you can send a message in a room:
io.sockets.in(room).emit('new_message',{"msg":"hi there"});
```

PS:
This is a kind of group chat where the group contains 2 members i.e. Client and a manager. For reference you can see this links:

http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/
https://github.com/jgonera/socket.io-multichat

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clear response, i have already a message schema, i will then create another schema for rooms.
The things i don't understand is how to create a dynamic room? i mean if a client has an id "789878985s29287a" can i create a dynamic room name (or id) with that?

Comment: @ikalangita How do we save the messages in database?

Comment: @DarkKnight https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

Answer (score 0):

In socket.io each socket has an individual ID which you can use to communicate between particular sockets. You can assign a particular value to the ID if you want, for example the user's MongoDB _id, for example:

```
this.userEmit(userID).emit('got user settings', settings);
// where userEmit is a custom function that will handle an error case when the id can't be found
```

You can also broadcast to specific "rooms", whereby only sockets that are members of that room will receive the message, e.g.:

```
        io.sockets.in(groupID).emit('update group status', {
            groupID: groupID,
            onlineMembers: x.length
        });
```

See their documentation for some examples: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Thank you, very helpful,